# Swift: Generate a set of (X) random 6 character substrings

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I am trying to generate 5 random substrings of six characters each from the alphabet. For example: ABCDEF, RSTUVW, UVWXYZ, etc. These substrings can be duplicates, so generating ABCDEF twice is a not a problem.

When I have these 5 substrings, I want to generate five arrays containing three characters. One of these characters should be the last letter of the substring and the other two letters should be two random unique letters from the entire alphabet.

Example:

Get five random substrings: 
[ABCDEF], [RSTUVW], [CDEFGH], [LMNOPQ], [UVWXYZ]

For [ABCDEF] the system could generate [F, H, S] and for [RSTUVW] it could generate [K, Q, W]. As you can see, the three-character arrays always contain the last letter of its substring and two other randomised unique letters.

The above is part of a game for kids to practice the order of the alphabet. In order to generate possible answers I actually need small sets of characters to assign to buttons.

What do you think is the best way to approach this?

Comment: When you generate the 5 substrings of 6 chars (in the initial phase) can these contains duplicate chars? Like `"ABABAB"`?

Comment: No, they have to be six consecutive letters from the alphabet. Thanks!

Comment: Why create 5 *arrays* of 6 characters, if only the last character of each array is relevant?

Comment: Because I also wanted to store the first five characters of the substring in order to display it. I guess you can also programmatically count five characters back from a random character and add this to the view.

Comment: It is not clear from your description which letters are used to generate the 3-character arrays.

Comment: For example: for the first random substring [ABCDEF] the program removes the letter F (last position) and adds it to a 3 character array together with two random other unique letters. This should be the case for every substring.

Comment: Two random letters from the entire alphabet, from that substring, or from the set of last letters?

Comment: From the entire alphabet :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Thanks to @vacawama here's a possible solution.*

### 1. Create the alphabet

```
let alphabet = Array("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters)
```

### 2. Create the 6 "sequences"

```
let sequences = (0..<5).map { _ -> String in
    let startIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(alphabet.count - 5)))
    let endIndex = startIndex + 5
    return String(alphabet[startIndex...endIndex])
}
```

> ["PQRSTU", "DEFGHI", "JKLMNO", "CDEFGH", "KLMNOP"]

### 3. Get the last char for each sequence

```
let lastChars = sequences.flatMap { $0.characters.last }
```

> ["U", "I", "O", "H", "P"]

### 4. Build 5 elms

Here's the code snippet

```
let elms = lastChars.map { char0 -> String in
    var tempAlphabet = alphabet
    tempAlphabet.removeAtIndex(tempAlphabet.indexOf(char0)!)
    let index1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tempAlphabet.count)))
    let char1 = tempAlphabet.removeAtIndex(index1)
    let index2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tempAlphabet.count)))
    let char2 = tempAlphabet[index2]
    return String(Array(Set<Character>([char0, char1, char2])))
}
```

> ["DUN", "ZIQ", "ROP", "HSW", "PGS"]

### Update

*Here's another solution to fix the problem hightligted by @dfri in the comments below. The following code snipped could replace the previous bullet **4.***

```
extension Array {
    mutating func removeRandom() -> Element {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
        return removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}

var availableChars = Array(Set(alphabet).subtract(lastChars))
let elms = lastChars.map { String([$0, availableChars.removeRandom(), availableChars.removeRandom()]) }
```

Comment: ThanksI I changed the first array to 0... 4 because I only need five sets. No problem!

However, the five three character arrays sometimes contain doubles :-( I want those to always have three unique characters (including the answer of course). 

["FGHIJKL", "CDEFGHI", "JKLMNOP", "TUVWXYZ", "GHIJKLM"]

["ZLI", "IML", "ZLI", "ZMM", "ZPZ"]

Comment: @DennisvanMazijk: I updated my answer. Now every word in the result contains unique chars.

Comment: @DennisvanMazijk: Actually there is another problem. If the first 5 words happen to be the same (as you are allowing) then we cannot produce a valid result. Infact `uniqueLastChars` will have only 1 char and then we will not be able to build the final result. I think we must force `sequences` to have at least 3 different elements.

Comment: @appzYourLife, see the comments above.  The 3-letter sequences should contain the last letter of a substring, and 2 random letters from the entire alphabet.

Comment: Wow! But as vacawama mentioned: the random two letters should be from the entire alphabet. That would make it work like a charm!

Comment: @vacawama: I updated my answer, I think now every condition is satisfied.

Comment: You're getting closer. ;-)  "ZY" is clearly not right.  I think you need to remove the last character from the alphabet before selecting the other two.  Also, I don't think it's necessary to create the array of unique last letters anymore.  You should also make sure you don't generate the same word twice.

Comment: @vacawama: you are correct again! Thank you, I am fixing it.

Comment: You should create one 3-character subarray for each last letter.  And I believe `Array(0...5).map` can be shortened to just `(0...5).map`.

Comment: @vacawama: Ok now every elm into the result contains 3 unique chars. 1 from `uniqueLastChars` and the other 2 from the `alphabet`. 

Comment: Instead of choosing the last character randomly, just create a 3-char array for each of the last letters.  I believe OP wants the 3-letter arrays to all be unique.

Comment: @vacawama: Ok but what if `uniqueLastChars` contains only 1 element? This happens if `sequences` contains always the same word.

Comment: There is not need to generate the unique last letters.  Even if last letters is `[A, A, A, A, A]` you can still generate 5 unique words `[ABC, AXZ, AHN, ABD, ACW]`.

Comment: @vacawama: Ok got it

Comment: @vacawama: Done, now it shows conform with the OP requirements.

Comment: It's working, but I get this error when running the code a couple of times. 

fatal error: Index out of range

Thank you for your help so far, guys! Really appreciate it ;-) and also learned some new tricks to work with arrays and characters!

Comment: @DennisvanMazijk: Please try again, that was the old version.

Comment: YES! You did it :D exactly what I was looking for. I will mark this as the answer. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @DennisvanMazijk: most of the credit goes to `@vacawama`

Comment: @appzYourLife, hardly most, but I'll take partial credit :-).  Up voted.

Comment: Nice work! Note though that there's still a small possibility of two three-letter words in `elms` to be the same, but it should be rather uncommon. To really ascertain uniqueness is quite a complex problem (easiest but not neatly remedied by brute-force double-checking computed words, and re-generating non-unique ones), but the neat solution above should certainly suffice in practice.

Comment: @dfri: Interesting, could you tell me more?

Comment: Sure, this was an interesting Q&A :) First of all, I'm don't think this was even a demand from the OP, but say e.g. for a case (to simplify) where `lastChars = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]`, a low-possibility outcome for for `elms` could be one of duplicates, e.g. `["DAK", "MAY", "DAK", "HZA", "UAE"]` (`"DAK"` duplicated). The problem, given `lastChars` (of say, length 5), to generate 5 _unique_ three-letter words (under constraint of corresponding `lastChars` character inclusion) is quite complex, as we'd need to, for each new word generated, ascertain it wont duplicate ones previously generated

Comment: There exists two quite simple (and kind of bad) solutions to this: **1.** categorise words to be generated into, say, a dictionary (`[String:[String]]`) where the key holds the `lastChars` (that must be included), and for generating words in each key-array, subsequently remove letters from alphabet as they have been used, and also, do not allow the use of characters that are present as other keys in the dictionary (mostly bad since we will then never generate, for key `A`, say `ABC` and `ACB`, since generating the former will remove `BC` from letter pool when generating the latter). ...

Comment: **1** is bad since we don't consider `ABC` and `ACB` duplicates, and want to allow these. **2** The second bad solution would be the brute-force approach: for each generated word (excluding the first one), double check against previously generated words so that the new one does not break uniqueness, and if it does: re-generate it. Really not a good one, but probably viable in practice.

Comment: Then to **3**, which would be an actual good solution that guarantees uniqueness (note that I still think your solution above is a _good_ solution even it doesn't guarantee uniqueness; shouldn't be a problem in practice): I guess this could use the same approach as **1** initially (categorise into `[String:[String]]` dictionary w.r.t. which letter that must be included, from `lastChars`), but randomly generate, for each word, letter by letter from a pool that dynamically excludes (for say, third letter) letters that would yield duplication of priorly generated words.

Comment: (and that was my last comment!) In practice **2** and **3** would mostly yield the same performance, but in theory, **3** converges (in math terms; is guaranteed to terminate, I guess, are better words here), whereas **2**, as all brute-force re-perform-random solution, is not guaranteed to terminate, in theory (even though we know it will, in practice). <-- last comment!

Comment: @dfri: congrats and thank you for detecting the issue. I added a new section to my answer that uses a shared pool of chars in order to guarantee unique generation of each elm.

Comment: Your addition solves the uniqueness issue, and you are way beyond answering the OP:s question! But note that the added solution is somewhat solution **1**: there are now no overlap at all in characters between the 3-letter words in `elms`. This is a great answer though, so note that I never meant that the loosely described **3** above should be implemented! Just pointed out, for the discussion, the somewhat complex matter of generating 3-letter words (under constraints) _randomly_ but while guaranteeing uniqueness. Where by randomly, allowing random characters from the full set of ...

Comment: ... characters for each word, with only minor dynamic removals from the character set to ascertain uniqueness (still allowing e.g. both `ABC` and `ACB` to both be generated). But again, great answer with now two different good alternatives to use in practice; se this just as a note/discussion between the two of us regarding the theoretical aspect of this subject!

Comment: My question really made you guys think about the problem. Nice to see an educated conversation regarding possible outcomes. To simply put it: my goal is to generate five questions. Each question will have three answers. The student will have to complete a set a of characters by choosing the last letter of the subset. That's why I wanted the last letter of ABCDEF in an array, together with two other possible answers. In the app, I will eventually hide the letter F from the student; they will have to choose the correct letter from that small pool of characters.

Comment: Or is it better to change the code so that it only returns 1 subset and 1 pool of answers every time the app generates a question? If I want to generate 10 questions, it would probably crash. However, the new code is actually pretty nice, because it returns all the last letters I need and also all the possible wrong answers. I can then select two random answers from the "availableChars" array and display them on screen together with the correct answer. I'm not really sure which approach is better (load/memory/etc).

Answer (score 0):

**Random substrings:**

```
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
    let charactersString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    let n = UInt32(charactersString.characters.count)
    var out = ""
    for _ in 0..<length {
        let index = charactersString.startIndex.advancedBy(Int(arc4random_uniform(n)))
        out.append(charactersString[index])
    }

    return out
}
```

**Get 5 Strings:**

```
func createSubstrings() -> [String] {
    var array = [String]()
    for _ in 0...5 {
        array.append(self.randomString(6))
    }
    return array
}
```

**Last array:**

```
func createFinalStrings() -> [String] {
    let substrings = createSubstrings()
    var finalStrings = [String]()
    let lastChars = substrings.flatMap { $0.characters.last }

    for _ in 0...5 {
        var string = ""
        while string.characters.count < 3 {
            let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
            let lastChar = lastChars[index]
            if string.rangeOfString(String(lastChar)) == nil{
                string = string + String(lastChar)
            }
        }
        finalStrings.append(string)
    }

    return finalStrings
}
```

Comment: I had to fix some errors, but this one is still blocking:

Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'UInt32'

Xcode says it's somewhere in the the lastChar function.

Comment: @DennisvanMazijk  I updated my answer removing that function, check the last version please